# Framer.js: how to get tap coordinates

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

I'm writing a Framer.js function to simulate the 'splash' effect when you tap a button or a layer, as per Google Material Design.

It looks something like this

```
tapSplash = (tapX,tapY) ->
   tapSplashLayer = new layer
       backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
       opacity: 0.2
       width: 500, height: 1500
       borderRadius: 1500
       midX: tapX
       midY: tapY
```

After this, I have some code to run the animation.

My question is, how do I get the tapX and tapY coordinates? It is not good enough to use the midpoint of the layer that has been clicked/tapped - I want the animation to originate from the exact point the user tapped on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your own answer to the question.
I've since then forked it and made changes so that taps on a computer or taps on a mobile device are recognized separately.
https://github.com/carignanboy1/Material-Design-Interactions/tree/improved-touch

```coffeescript
touchEvent = Events.touchEvent(event)

if Utils.isPhone() || Utils.isTablet()
        tX = touchEvent.clientX - layer.x
        tY = touchEvent.clientY - layer.y
    else
        tX = touchEvent.offsetX
        tY = touchEvent.offsetY
```

Comment: Awesome @carigna.boy. Yes, I forgot to come back here and answer my own question. Thanks for looking into it